# Vbnullstring concatenated with a string vs vbnullstring

Tags: vb6

```
Dim str as string
str & vbnullstring <> vbnullstring 
str <> vbnullstring
```

What is the difference between lines 2 & 3?

Comment: Nothing.  Easy enough to test.

Comment: I suspect somebody is confused about several entirely different things such as `vbNullString`, `vbNullChar`, and `Null`.

Answer (score 1):

Anything `& vbNullString` will get you the same string, so the two lines should be the same.

If you have issues in the program you may try `Option Explicit` because `&` has strange behaviors when dealing with `Variant`. If you wrote something like `Dim str, a As String` then `str` has type `Variant`.

Comment: It isn't "strange behavior" at all.  The difference is that a `Variant` can be 'vbEmpty' or 'vbNull" and a `String` can't.  Consider:  `Dim foo As Variant: foo = vbNull & vbNullString: Debug.Print foo = vbNullString`

Comment: @Comintern No, vbNull is constant 1 and vbEmpty is constant 0. & is not *quite* strange but it has a complex behavior. Basically, it converts both variables into strings and joins them, where `Empty` and `Null` are both converted to `vbNullString`.

Comment: Did you run the code in the comment? That directly contradicts the assertion that `vbEmpty` and `vbNull` are converted to `vbNullString`. Try these: `Debug.Print vbNullString & vbNullString = vbNullString 'True` - `Debug.Print vbNull & vbNullString = vbNullString 'False` - `Debug.Print vbNull = vbNullString 'Type mismatch error`

Comment: @Comintern Yes I did, in VB6. The object explorer says `vbNull` and `vbEmpty` is in the enum `VbVarType` and is used as the return value of `VarType`, so I used `Null` and `Empty` instead of the `vbNull` and `vbEmpty` you mentioned. `Debug.Print vbNull = vbNullString` **does** return "Type mismatch error" but that's because vbNull is a numeric. I tried `Debug.Print Null = vbNullString` but the result is "Null". Please try `Debug.Print vbNull  '1` - you seem to have made a mistake here.